# Angular 5: ng build -- prod failing when looking for unused library

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ng2-completer

My app is under **Angular 5.2.6**

things are normal with `ng serve`

But when running : `ng build --prod` , it takes a while , before failing , and giving along trace of errors .

Those errors seems to look for files inside a library folder that even i'm not using now.

*this is a part of the error:*

```
looking for modules in /home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/frontend_v2/src
        using description file: /home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/frontend_v2/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/frontend_v2/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: /home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/frontend_v2/package.json (relative path: ./src/ng2-completer/services/remote-data)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/frontend_v2/src/ng2-completer/services/remote-data doesn't exist
            .ts
```

it seems that it searches for **src/ng2-completer**  , but even i'm not using it .

Here is my **package.json** :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "karma": "ng test",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:ci": "jest --runInBand",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.6",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "angular2-drag-scroll": "1.2.6",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "1.3.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^2.0.5",
    "json2typescript": "1.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.12.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-http-interceptor": "^3.1.2",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.2",
    "ngx-filesaver": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-modialog": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "npm": "^5.2.0",
    "proxy-polyfill": "^0.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.3.5",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jest": "^20.0.5",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^20.0.7",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!json2typescript|angular2-multiselect-dropdown|ngx-filesaver|ngx-bootstrap|angular2-drag-scroll)"
    ]
  }
}
```

i ve cleaned npm cache , deleted the **package-lock.json**  , and re-installed **node_modules** , but all that did not made it work.

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: does it work with --aot=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the GitHub page for @angular-cli (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). I believe this was a known issue that has been fixed with version 1.7+

There was a dependency that needed an update.

Comment: : yeah it seems to not appear when installing 1.7.0 , but it throws another eror which is know as not resolved yet  :  92% chunk asset optimization/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/frontend_v2/node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/input-source-map-tracker.js:37
  if (originalPosition.line === null && line > 1 && selectorFallbacks > 0) {